# TypeError: Unsupported Operand Type--float and NoneType --using Python and DocX

Tags: python, excel, docx

Created a small program using python to read data from an excel file utilizing DocX to generate a word document from the data.  My code has been working for the most part but on occasion keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

It is referencing this line here:

```
stock_sum = sum(stock_data['total'] for stock_data in stockData.values())
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's generating this error.  I've double checked the data in excel and the values in question are all numbers with no text.

Here is a closer look at the beginning of the code:

```
import urllib.request
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import openpyxl, pprint, math, datetime
from collections import OrderedDict
print('Opening workbook...')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('stocks.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('stock_list')
sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sp500')
ei = wb.get_sheet_by_name('ei')
garp = wb.get_sheet_by_name('garp')
spmktcap = wb.get_sheet_by_name('spmktcap')
stockData = {}


number_stocks = 0

client_name = input("What is client's name?: " )
analyst_name = input("What is your name?: ")
analyst_email = input("What is your email?: ")
analyst_extension = input("What is your extension?:")


#assign values from stock list to stockData dictionary
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    # Each row in the spreadsheet has data for one census tract.
    ticker = sheet['A' + str(row)].value
    shares = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    company_name = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    sector = sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    price = sheet['E' + str(row)].value
    total = sheet['F' + str(row)].value
    beta = sheet['G' + str(row)].value
    dividend = sheet['H' + str(row)].value
    mktcap = sheet['I' + str(row)].value
    number_stocks+=1

    # Make sure the key for this ticker exists.
    stockData.setdefault(ticker,{})
    stockData[ticker]['company_name'] = company_name
    stockData[ticker]['sector'] = sector
    stockData[ticker]['shares'] = shares
    stockData[ticker]['price'] = price
    stockData[ticker]['total'] = total
    stockData[ticker]['dividend'] = dividend
    stockData[ticker]['beta'] = beta
    stockData[ticker]['mktcap'] = mktcap


#get total portfolio value
stock_sum = sum(stock_data['total'] for stock_data in stockData.values())

#add percentages for each stock to dictionary
for stock_data in stockData.values():
    stock_data['percentage'] = stock_data['total']/stock_sum

portfolio_beta = sum(stock['beta']*stock['percentage'] for stock in stockData.values())

portfolio_yield = sum(stock['dividend']*stock['percentage'] for stock in stockData.values())
portfolio_yield = portfolio_yield/100
# print(portfolio_beta)

market_cap = sum(stock['mktcap']*stock['percentage'] for stock in stockData.values())
mkt_cap_bill = market_cap/1000
```

Comment: Could there be blank values at the end of the Excel sheets?

Comment: You need to look at the data in question. More importantly, you should probably pre-process the values, replacing `None` with `0` or `NaN` as appropriate. (Maybe it really is an error...)

Comment: Ok so i closed the brackets.  Didn't help.  I deleted the entire column in excel and replaced it.  Didn't help.  BUT so i did print out the data in python and for the 'total' field it is showing up in python as a formula ('=e7*b7') -which is totally baffling me.  The values are pasted in from another sheet that utilized this formula---but are pasted in as values.  And there is no formula in that field!

Comment: So...think i figured it out.  When i looked at the data in python there was one entry being recorded as a 'None' value---so figuring this must have been an empty row somewhere in excel as I deleted all of the lower rows.  Curious does anyone know of a easy implementation to ensure that extra rows don't get added accidentally in excel?  This program will be shared by a few users and i can see this being a problem in the future.

Comment: @JohnRogerson: have you explored putting the data into a database instead of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the data looking for `None`, which probably comes from blank cells or computation errors in the sheets.

In the short term, replace this:

```
stock_sum = sum(stock_data['total'] for stock_data in stockData.values())
```

with this:

```
stock_sum = sum(0 if stock_data['total'] is None else stock_data['total'] for stock_data in stockData.values())
```

Comment: when i change this--error is now this:                       stock_data['percentage'] = stock_data['total']/stock_sum
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'